# Why Resume and Cover letter are location specific?

Tags: resume, cover-letter

I have been getting lot of calls from Job Websites. They are claiming that my Resume/Cover letter is not as per Canadian, US, Singapore format. They are charging lot of money to change it into country specific format.

Let me give an idea how my resume look like (top to bottom):

**Header**

**Objective**

**Career Profile Summary**

**Achievements**

**Education details**

**Professional Experience**

**Personal Information**

If it really has to be country specific, then Why? I don't want to pay them such amount of money what are few websites where I can learn to write country specific resumes/cover-letter on my own.  Is this something I need to concern my self with or is this just someone wanting to get money from me for a service I really do not need?

Comment: That smells like a scam.

Comment: It does not just smell. It reeks.

Answer (score 15):

Ignore these calls, this is just money-making scam.

That said, there are cultural differences on how to present yourself in different Countries. It is a plus if you learn the style appropriate to where you are applying. Don´t overthink it though - company´s willing to hire from abroad are used to get different styles of applications and even locally the style varies from applicant to applicant.

Comment: Exactly this.  +1, and +50 if it were allowed.

Comment: And mostly what you have looks fine for the US  except the personal information section which is generally not done in the US. And limit to 2 pages max. BTW, Objective is usually a screen out item, it can harm but almost never helps, so many people omit it now to save space.

Answer (score 0):

As to why things are location specific, different countries have different laws about what is legal to ask in an interview situation, so some things that might be standard in Germany are information that the interviewer cant know in the US and including it is likely to mean that your resume will get chucked by HR before the hiring officials see it.

Different locations have differing cultures and so what is most important in some countries is irrelevant in others.

Most people reviewing hundreds of resumes or CVs want things to be fairly standard to save time in reviewing, so it is worth your while to look up what is the norm in the countries you are applying to.

So, for example, in the US, few hiring managers read past the second page (and often only read the second page if they are interested in you), so if your most compelling information is on page five, the likelihood that anyone in the US will see it is low.